# General tree in C

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I want to build a general tree in C. The node of the tree has an array of strings and a list of children.

```
typedef struct treeNode {
    int numOfChildren;
    char** commands;
    struct treeNode** children;
} tNode;

tNode* head = (tNode*) malloc(sizeof(tNode));

tNode* node0 = (tNode*) malloc(sizeof(tNode));
tNode* node1 = (tNode*) malloc(sizeof(tNode));
node1->commands[0] = "hello";
```

When compile using gcc in Linux, it is giving me a segmentation error. Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also note that you didn't allocate any memory for `commands` or `children`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with

```
char** commands;
```

Is the wrong type.  This is a pointer to a pointer that holds a char.  So that when you do

```
node1->commands[0] = "hello";
```

It gets the address of `hello` and then interprets the contents at that address as a pointer to the string you thought you wanted to assign, and assigns that value to `commands[0]`, which is really just `commands`.  Which if course is computer gibberish and ends in your segmentation fault.

Either you have to have declare and use

```
char* commands;
...
node1->commands = "hello";
```

Or you need to create some intermediate pointer to assign to `commands`, such as `malloc`ing an additional block of memory somewhere, and filling that pointer with the address that points to `hello`.

For example

```
#define MAXNUMCMDS 10
...
char** commands;
…
tNode* node1 = malloc(sizeof(tNode));   
node1->commands = malloc(MAXNUMCMDS * sizeof(char*));
node1->commands[0] = "Hello";
node1->commands[1] = "World";
node1->commands[2] = "here";
node1->commands[3] = "is";
node1->commands[4] = "an";
node1->commands[5] = "example";
node1->commands[6] = "of";
node1->commands[7] = "an";
node1->commands[8] = "array of";
node1->commands[9] = "char*";
```

Of course, assigning something to commands[10] would be a big big mistake, as you would be writing past the end of the assigned array.

Also now when you free `node1`, you will also have to free `commands` (and technically you need to free `commands` first)

Comment: Then is there some how to declare an array of strings in C?